# My Java regex isn't capturing the group

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match the username with a regex. Please don't suggest a split.

```
USERNAME=geo
```

Here's my code:

```
    String input = "USERNAME=geo";
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("USERNAME=(\\w+)");
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(input);
    if(mat.find()) {
        System.out.println(mat.group());
    }
```

why doesn't it find `geo` in the group? I noticed that if I use the `.group(1)`, it finds the username. However the `group` method contains `USERNAME=geo`. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `group()` is equivalent to `group(0)`, and group 0 denotes the entire pattern.

From the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29):

> `public String group(int group)`
>
> Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression `m.group(0)` is equivalent to `m.group()`

As you've found out, with your pattern, `group(1)` gives you what you want.

If you insist on using `group()`, you'd have to modify the pattern to something like `"(?<=USERNAME=)\\w+"`.

Comment: `group()` does not always return whole string.

Comment: I meant to say "entire pattern". Corrected.

Comment: Indeed, as per the `Matcher` javadoc: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg *Group zero always stands for the entire expression.*

Comment: Nope, that's *previous*, not entire. You may try following: `Matcher m = Pattern.compile("a\\w").matcher("abacad"); while (m.find()) System.out.println(m.group()); ` -- it should print following lines: `ab ac ad`

Comment: BTW, cool pattern proposal for not to capture "USERNAME=" -- very clever (but a bit unreadable though).

Answer (score 3):

As `Matcher.group()` javadoc says, it "returns the input subsequence matched by the previous match", and the previous match in your case was "USERNAME=geo" since you've called `find()`.

In contrast, the method `group(int)` returns *specific* group. Capturing groups are numbered by counting their opening parentheses from left to right, so the first group would match "geo" in your case.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `group` is *supposed* to return the string matching the pattern in its entirety. For getting a *group* within that string, you need to pass the group number that you want.

See [here](http://www.baskent.edu.tr/~tkaracay/ders/prg/java/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29) for details, paraphrased below:

> **group**
>
> *public String group()*
>   Returns the input subsequence matched by the previous match.
>
> *public String group(int group)*
>   Returns the input subsequence captured by the given group during the previous match operation.
>   Capturing groups are indexed from left to right, starting at one. Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression m.group(0) is equivalent to m.group().

Answer (score 1):

So the VAR.group( int i ) will return the ith capture group of the regex. 
With 0 being the full string. You need to call .group( 1 )

Comment: Although your answer is fine, in the future you may want to elaborate a little more like the other respondents. "It's better to teach a man to fish etc..."

Answer (score 1):

For your solution, here's what works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "USERNAME=geo";
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("USERNAME=(\\w+)");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(input);
        if(mat.find()) {
            System.out.println(mat.group(1));
        }
    }
```

**Output**
geo

Reason

> **String java.util.regex.Matcher.group(int
>   group)** 
>   
> Returns the input subsequence
>   captured by the given group during the
>   previous match operation.
>
> For a matcher m, input sequence s, and
>   group index g, the expressions
>   m.group(g) and s.substring(m.start(g),
>   m.end(g)) are equivalent.